# Last_value window function doesn't work properly

Tags: oracle, window-functions

`Last_value` window function `doesn't` work properly.

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMP2
(
  CUSTOMER_ID  NUMBER(38)                       NOT NULL,
  VALID_FROM   DATE                             NOT NULL
);


Customer_id      Valid_from
-------------------------------------
 9775             06.04.2013 01:34:16
 9775             06.04.2013 20:34:00
 9775             12.04.2013 11:07:01
--------------------------------------

select DISTINCT LAST_VALUE(VALID_FROM) 
  OVER (partition by customer_id ORDER BY VALID_FROM ASC) rn 
from   examp1;
```

When I use `LAST_VALUE` then I get following rows:

```
06.04.2013 20:34:00
06.04.2013 01:34:16
12.04.2013 11:07:01
```

When I use `FIRST_VALUE` then I get following rows:

```
select  DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(VALID_FROM) 
OVER (partition by customer_id ORDER BY VALID_FROM DESC) rn 
from   examp1;

4/12/2013 11:07:01 AM
```

`First_value` query gives correct output. I hoped to get same output from these queries.   Why do I have `2 different results`?

Comment: This applies to **Microsoft SQL Server** as well

Comment: @Jaider It applies to most of the RDBMSes, because it is defined that way in SQL Standard. One that deviates from that rule is [Snowflake - Window Frame Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-frame-usage-notes)

Answer (score 14):

In analytic functions you need to specify window range. By default it is `between unbounded preceding and current row`, which I assume to be self-explanatory.

Basically, this is what happens when you specify `partition by customer_id order by valid_from asc`:

1. Oracle takes all rows matching current row's `customer id`
2. It orders them in an ascending order by `valid_from`
3. It forms a window starting with minimum `valid_from` date, and ending with current row's `valid_from`.
4. It evaluates `last_value`, which returns your current row's `valid_from`.

What you need to do is specify an ongoing range:

```
16:53:00 SYSTEM@sandbox> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\sandbox\BUFFER_SYSTEM_38.sql

  1  select last_value(VALID_FROM) OVER (
  2    partition by customer_id
  3    ORDER BY VALID_FROM asc
  4    range between current row and unbounded following
  5  ) rn
  6* from   t
16:53:21 SYSTEM@sandbox> /

RN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-DEC-13 11.07.01.000000 AM
04-DEC-13 11.07.01.000000 AM
04-DEC-13 11.07.01.000000 AM

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Answer (score 10):

`first_value` and `last_value` are a bit special in that they require a window on which to operate.

You need to add `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` as follows:

```
select DISTINCT LAST_VALUE(VALID_FROM) OVER (partition by customer_id
  ORDER BY VALID_FROM ASC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) rn
from examp1;
```

See the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407 and read especially the section on windowing.

Note that the default clause for functions which accept the windowing clause is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` which explains why one order works while the other doesn't! The default clause is set this way to make it easy to do running-total type calculations without having to specify the window.

Comment: I would add that [`NTH_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions114.htm#SQLRF30031) has the same behaviour