# Oracle: LAST_VALUE vs FIRST_VALUE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this view:

```
ORGANIZATION_ID|INVENTORY_ITEM_ID|ITEM_COST|PERIOD_DATE        |
---------------|-----------------|---------|-------------------|
           1271|            37061|    49.64|2019-02-28 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    50.15|2019-01-31 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    58.99|2018-12-31 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    56.85|2018-11-30 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    34.78|2018-10-31 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    44.91|2018-09-30 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    44.05|2018-08-31 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    20.84|2018-07-31 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    19.95|2018-06-30 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    18.56|2018-05-31 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    17.42|2018-04-30 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    13.62|2018-03-31 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    13.62|2018-02-28 23:59:59|
           1271|            37061|    13.62|2018-01-31 23:59:59|
```

When I do FIRST_VALUE:

```
SELECT UNIQUE FIRST_VALUE(ITEM_COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_DATE DESC) 
FROM SOMEVIEW 
WHERE INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 37061 
AND ORGANIZATION_ID = 1271
```

I get:

```
FIRST_VALUE(ITEM_COST)OVER(ORDERBYPERIOD_DATEDESC)|
--------------------------------------------------|
                                             49.64|
```

As desired.

When I do LAST_VALUE

```
SELECT UNIQUE LAST_VALUE(ITEM_COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_DATE DESC) 
FROM SOMEVIEW 
WHERE INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 37061 
AND ORGANIZATION_ID = 1271
```

I get:

```
LAST_VALUE(ITEM_COST)OVER(ORDERBYPERIOD_DATEDESC)|
-------------------------------------------------|
                                            49.64|
                                            56.85|
                                            44.05|
                                            18.56|
                                            34.78|
                                            19.95|
                                            20.84|
                                            13.62|
                                            58.99|
                                            44.91|
                                            50.15|
                                            17.42|
```

Shouldn't it be 13.62? And also, why does the select return all those values? I checked the documentation and don't get it.

I even tried adding more columns to the order by such as Org_ID, same result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274362/last-value-window-function-doesnt-work-properly

Answer (score 4):

Because default window is

```
range between unbounded preceding and current row
```